# OpenCL casting when accessing array

Tags: opencl

I was reading Apple's OpenCL [reduction example](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/samplecode/OpenCL_Parallel_Reduction_Example/Listings/reduce_float_kernel_cl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008188-reduce_float_kernel_cl-DontLinkElementID_7), and noticed there's a macro for accessing array elements:

```
#define LOAD_GLOBAL_F1(s, i) \
((__global const float*)(s))[(size_t)(i)]
```

It was used like this:

```
float a = LOAD_GLOBAL_F1(input, i);
```

where `input` is of type `__global const float *` and `i` is `size_t`.

Why is `float a = input[i]` not used here?  Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it could be. Perhaps the macros were left over from something that needed the casting.

Answer (score 0):

In this example the code code have been written not using the macros as you suggest. Why the macros are used is anyone's guess: code reused from somewhere else; a C based kernel test framework; the code author feeling it improved readability; etc., etc.